# Full Text Search query contains column

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

Is it possible to do the opposite of a CONTAINS in SQL Server? I want my query to match the column, not the opposite. For example:

Not this:

```
WHERE CONTAINS(Description, '"Just A Test"')
```

But this:

```
WHERE CONTAINS('"Just A Test"', Description)
```

It's of course possible with a LIKE but that's rather slow and I'd like to use FTS for this.

Comment: Only yesterday a very similar question was asked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47602454/5857386 . Pls, use search before asking new questions.

Comment: @andrews, that's not the same.

Comment: what's the point of switching search term and the searched full-indexed column? Why do you need that?

Comment: Because the database is used for lookup, my input text is longer than the text in database.